# Checkbox Toggle to Set Address Fields

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I'm using asp.net + MVC and trying to build an interface where one would enter the address of a facility. In some instances, the facility can have the same address as the institution it belongs to and I’m using a checkbox (EditFor field) to indicate if the address is the same as the institution. The view is strongly typed to a Facility class and this class has a virtual property to the Institution class. My issue is when one clicks the checkbox I would like the code to update the address fields to either display the institution’s address or clear the fields so one can enter a different address. I have some javascript that I used to hide/show the address fields but that’s not really what I want. How can I collect the model data i.e. Institution and Facility and place it in the EditFor fields?

**Checkbox Field**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#AddressSameAsInstitute").click(function () {
        $(".set-from-checkbox").toggle(!this.checked);
    });
```

**Update**
As noted below, I believe I can use @Model.Institution... But I’m not sure what javascript code to use that will set the text property of an EditFor control?

Comment: Just had a thought. Are C# variables available to JavaScript code?

Comment: So I believe I can use @Model.Institution... But I’m not sure what javascript code to use that will set the text property of an EditFor control?

Comment: Please post source html for issues related to client side. We shouldn't have to mentally parse your server code to figure out how the browser sees it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little note to start off with: any of the "controls" that ASP.NET offers are translated to HTML elements that the browser will understand.  The `EditorFor` control, for instance, translates to an `<input type='text' />` in most cases.  In order to interact with these elements in javascript, you need to know which types of controls you're dealing with in the HTML document, and not so much from the .NET perspective.

To copy text/value from one element to another in javascript, you need to know the `id` on the source and target elements (or a `class` if it's specific to each element).  Using JQuery, the code would look like this:

```
$('#chkCopyAddress').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#instAddress').val($('#facAddress').val());
            $('#instCity').val($('#facCity').val());
            $('#instState').val($('#facState').val());
        } else {
            $('#instAddress').val('');
            $('#instCity').val('');
            $('#instState').val('');
        }
    });
```

So I would suggest putting an `id` on the elements you're creating with ASP.NET.  It looks like there's room for duplicate IDs when using the `EditorFor` control (which defeats the purpose of IDs) since it seems to use the model's property names for an `id` as noted in [this MSDN atricle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

I've also put together a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg4utr2a/) to demonstrate the desired functionality in case seeing it in action helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan - I was using .text = string which wasn’t working. My problem, as it stands currently, is that when I try to use @Model.Institution.Name it is giving me a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Never mind. I’m kind of a dar dar on this one. I’m working on the Create Facility view so there is no Facility yet and thus no Institution. Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion.